# How to apply transaction logic in FastAPI RealWorld example app?

Tags: python, fastapi, asyncpg

I am using [nsidnev/fastapi-realworld-example-app](https://github.com/nsidnev/fastapi-realworld-example-app).

I need to apply transaction logic to this project.

In one API, I am calling a lot of methods from repositories and doing updating, inserting and deleting operations in many tables. If there is an exception in any of these operations, how can I roll back changes?
(Or if everything is correct then commit.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nsidnev/fastapi-realworld-example-app](https://github.com/nsidnev/fastapi-realworld-example-app) is using [asyncpg](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/).

There are two ways to use [Transactions](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#transactions).

## 1. `async with` statement

```py
async with conn.transaction():
    await repo_one.update_one(...)
    await repo_two.insert_two(...)
    await repo_three.delete_three(...)

    # This automatically rolls back the transaction:
    raise Exception
```

## 2. `start`, `rollback`, `commit` statements

```py
tx = conn.transaction()
await tx.start()

try:
    await repo_one.update_one(...)
    await repo_two.insert_two(...)
    await repo_three.delete_three(...)
except:
    await tx.rollback()
    raise
else:
    await tx.commit()
```

---

## Getting the connection `conn` in routes

Inject `conn: Connection = Depends(_get_connection_from_pool)`.

```py
from asyncpg.connection import Connection
from fastapi import Depends

from app.api.dependencies.database import _get_connection_from_pool


@router.post(
    ...
)
async def create_new_article(
    ...
    conn: Connection = Depends(_get_connection_from_pool),  # Add this
) -> ArticleInResponse:
```